# No longer able to run Websphere Application Server v6.0 on my IBM RAD

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I'm currently using a development machine for my java development works built by my colleagues. IBM RAD setup on this machine has IBM Websphere Portal setup with the server profile "Websphere Application Server v6.0" running, so I can test portal via the browser with "http://localhost:9081/wps/portal/home".

Today, I'm trying to setup my own dynamic web project on the RAD. When it comes to running the web application I accidentally override the server profile (Websphere Application Server v6.0) that the IBM Websphere Portal was using. What I did was I right click on my new project Run -> Run on Server -> Choose an existing server -> Websphere Application Server v6.0 -> Next -> Add and remove projects -> I added my new project to the right box -> Finish, which started the server automatically. After few minutes of "Starting...", the console display an error:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 6.0 [BASE 6.0.0.0 o0444.14]  running with process name wnab611300Node01Cell\wnab611300Node01\server1 and process id 2844
Host Operating System is Windows XP, version 5.1
Java version = J2RE 1.4.2 IBM Windows 32 build cn142sr1w-20041028 (JIT enabled: jitc),     Java Compiler = jitc, Java VM name = Classic VM
was.install.root = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6
user.install.root = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/profiles/default
Java Home = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/java/lib;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/profiles/default/classes;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/classes;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/installedChannels;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib/ext;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/web/help;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/profiles/default/properties;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/properties;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib/j2ee.jar;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6/lib/urlprotocols.jar
Java Library path = C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6\java\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6\bin;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6\java\bin;C:\IBM\Rational\SDP\6.0\runtimes\base_v6\java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Attachmate\EXTRA!\;C:\Program Files\Rational\common;C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[14/01/13 16:37:36:873 EST] 0000000a ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[14/01/13 16:37:36:967 EST] 0000000a MBeanDescript W   ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com/ibm/ws/management/descriptor/xml/mbeans.xml.
[14/01/13 16:37:37:014 EST] 0000000a AdminInitiali A   ADMN0015I: The administration service is initialized.
[14/01/13 16:37:37:779 EST] 0000000a SystemOut     O PLGC0057I: Plug-in configuration service is started successfully.
[14/01/13 16:37:37:795 EST] 0000000a PMIImpl       A   PMON0001A: PMI is enabled
[14/01/13 16:37:38:201 EST] 0000000a CGBridgeServi I   CWRCB0204E: The core group bridge service is disabled because it may not execute on a non-managed node.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:217 EST] 0000000a SibMessage    I   [:] CWSIU0000I: Release: WAS60.SIB Level: o0444.10
[14/01/13 16:37:38:232 EST] 0000000a SecurityDM    I   SECJ0231I: The Security component's FFDC Diagnostic Module com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityDM registered successfully: true.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:373 EST] 0000000a AuditServiceI A   SECJ6004I: Security Auditing is disabled. 
[14/01/13 16:37:38:435 EST] 0000000a distSecurityC I   SECJ0309I: Java 2 Security is disabled.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:467 EST] 0000000a Configuration A   SECJ0215I: Successfully set JAAS login provider configuration class to com.ibm.ws.security.auth.login.Configuration.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:467 EST] 0000000a distSecurityC I   SECJ0212I: WCCM JAAS configuration information successfully pushed to login provider class.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:482 EST] 0000000a distSecurityC I   SECJ0240I: Security service initialization completed successfully
[14/01/13 16:37:38:607 EST] 0000000a ObjectPoolSer I   OBPL0007I: Object Pool Manager service is disabled.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:623 EST] 0000000a J2EEServiceMa I   ASYN0059I: Work Manager service initialized successfully.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:654 EST] 0000000a CScopeCompone I   CSCP0002I: Compensation service is disabled.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:701 EST] 0000000a SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0006I: The SIB service was not enabled and will not be started.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:717 EST] 0000000a ActivitySessi I   WACS0045I: ActivitySession service is disabled.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:732 EST] 0000000a SOAPContainer I   WSWS1062I: SOAP Container Service has been initialized.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:764 EST] 0000000a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0036I: The Scheduler Service is initializing.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:779 EST] 0000000a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0037I: The Scheduler Service has been initialized.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:889 EST] 0000000a StartUpServic I   STUP0008I: The Startup Beans service is disabled.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:889 EST] 0000000a I18nService   I   I18N0010I: The Internationalization service is created on server1.
[14/01/13 16:37:38:889 EST] 0000000a I18nServiceSe I   I18N0010I: The Internationalization service is disabled on server1.
[14/01/13 16:37:39:326 EST] 0000000a ORBRas        E com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket P=859170:O=0:CT ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread. Exception=[ java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind ].
[14/01/13 16:37:44:357 EST] 0000000a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0040I: The Scheduler Service is stopping.
[14/01/13 16:37:44:357 EST] 0000000a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0002I: The Scheduler Service has stopped.
[14/01/13 16:37:44:373 EST] 0000000a AppProfileCom I   ACIN0009I: The application profiling service is stopping.
[14/01/13 16:37:44:373 EST] 0000000a ActivitySessi I   WACS0049I: The ActivitySession service is stopping.
[14/01/13 16:37:44:420 EST] 0000000a WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
META-INF/ws-server-components.xml
[14/01/13 16:37:44:467 EST] 0000000a WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:182)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:120)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:378)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:190)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:347)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:821)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:649)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:356)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:173)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:733)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:143)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1282)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1839)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:368)
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:82)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:174)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:339)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:340)
... 13 more
```

Extremely regreted what I did, which I should've used "Manually define a server" instead of "Choose an existing server" when running my new web project. 
Now I couldn't get my Portal application back, no matter what I do. I've done research online, some posts say it could be conflicting ports used, some suggested to stop java.exe in task manager, but none worked. Even tried to reboot the machine, no luck. Finally tried to create a new server profile using "Manually define a server", but still getting the same error.
In summary, two questions:
1. How do I get my Portal application back?
2. How do I setup a second web project on the same machine as the existing Portal application?

Answer (score 0):

Some process is using a port that is needed by WebSphere.

First try to restart the server, sometimes if WebSphere crashes the port doesn't get released properly.

If that doesn't help you need to identify which process is using the port.

See [Port number settings in WebSphere Application Server versions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rins_portnumber.html) to see the default ports (if you didn't change them) and the files the ports are configured in.

Then run `netstat` and look for a process that is using any of these ports, needless to say you need to make sure it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Aviram, I cannot find portdef.props file you mentioned. Also netstat -anp returns no entries

Comment: Edited to question, I thought we are talking about linux

Comment: Sorry Aviram, there's no portdef.props or portdef.properties file exist in the directory you mentioned

Comment: Sorry, gave you an answer for 6.1

Comment: anyone has an answer to my question?

Comment: The link I added is for 6.0 so the a look there

Answer (score 0):

Avrim is right. A network port isnt released and WebSphere complains about it - in a WebSphere Corba way.
However you could also edit the serverindex.xml to change the ports.

[This blog post discribes how to do that](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/08/websphere-port-conflicts-while-starting.html)